# Standard Common Practice Method in Solidity to perfrom any type of division?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I am trying to do the following calculation with solidity:
3,000 / 45,000,000 = 0.000067 with the following method:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

function divide(uint _num1, uint _num2) public pure returns(uint _result) {
    return (_num1 /_num2 );
}
```

But obviously, I am getting the results as zero.

I am aware that solidity for transactions uses 18 decimal points (using Wei), however, I could not find in the replay to all the previous questions regarding the decimals in solidity how to do it for regular numbers, or regular calculations. Also most of the time it does not even work with transactions.

What is the actual commonly used standard practice method to do "ANY" division from "ANY" number, regardless being for Ether, Tokens, or regular calculations?
I mean a method that would work for 3 / 100 just as well as 2.5 / 3.7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floating-point arithmetics are not supported in Solidity however you can use fixed-point arithmetics considering that you have 18 points of decimals if you use `uint256`.